# php session recreated in each ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, session, jquery-mobile, cross-domain

I'm trying to write a mobile web app with JqueryMobile, the mobile will be my client, I also have a php service that will manage login sessions, but the php creates a new session in each ajax calls, I see the generated session files in my session file path, I need to resume the php sessions.

The php file is look like this :

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require 'connect_to_db.php';

// Starting the session
session_name('MySessionName');

// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);

session_start();
...
// checking if loged in ...
?>
```

and the ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "login.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        command: "Login",
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response)
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#DataList");
    },
});
```

I checked many pages from stackoverflow but no success.
I'm testing my app in firefox and xampp.

Comment: You may want to add the code which checks if you are logged in to your example as the problem may be further in than you have shown

Comment: Alternatively check that your connect_to_db.php script does not contain a session_start also

Comment: no there is no session_start in my connect_to_db.php.

Answer (score 0):

Check the request/response headers of the request with the developer tools of your browser. The response headers should contain something like:

```
Set-Cookie: MySessionName=abcdef12345; expires=Wed, 21-May-2014 10:46:20 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

After the first request, the next request need to send the cookie back.

```
Cookie: MySessionName=abcdef12345
```

It is possible that the browser does not accept the cookie (lifetime, 3party, p3p policy, ...). If that's the case and it does not send the session id back, PHP can not identify it and will create a new one.

Comment: Thanx Thomas, there is no Cookie in my second ajax, even with    adding xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
      },

Comment: So the problem seems to be in the cookie options. I suggest opening the ajax request directly in the browser (own tab or window). If the the same happens on direct requests, it is something in the cookie options (domain, path, lifetime, ...).